# Convert home POTS wiring to Cat5e Ethernet

Tags: ethernet

I have a house where the builder used in wall Cat5e to wire all the telephone jacks. All the boxes (total 4 boxes) are wired in series (one  Cat5 wire in then another Cat5 wire out to another box).

I want to convert this to Ethernet since I have no need for POTS.

- Is it possible at each one of the boxes to connect to a small PoE switch (3 port min)?
- Can I have just one PoE injector at the end of the line to power everything?
- Is there a flush mount — or almost flush mount — solution where I can plug the two wires from the wall and then have one or more ports facing out?

Comment: *PoE Passthrough* switches  do exist, but I don't have any experience with them

Answer (score 0):

They're actually wired in parallel not series [though that's not really the deciding factor for Ethernet]. Think of Ethernet as needing something more tree-like, one root going out to many independent branches.

You can point to point any cable, but to make any useful ethernet network you must come out of the wall into a switch, then back to the next socket to be able to link them all. Each node needs two sockets, one for each of the existing cables. The network will only connect once each goes through a switch. You then plug each additional device into unused sockets on any of the switches. this gives you, rather than one 'tree', many smaller 'bushes'.
This is, of course, expensive in Ethernet switches, but might be cheaper & a lot simpler than getting someone to wire the house correctly to a single point.